# How to parse a line from a file into multiple lists

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing

I have a file that looks like this.

```
1,2,Room1 # first is the current room, the rest of the numbers the neighbours - maximum 4, and the last the name of the room
2,1,5,Room2
5,2,332,Room3
```

.... and so on

I want to parse it in order to use BFS algorithm. I tried:

```
with open( "data.txt", "r" ) as input_data:
  input_list= [map(int,num.split()) for num in input_data.readlines()]
```

I want to have a dictionary like this in order to apply BFS:

```
data = { '1':['2'], '2':['1','5'] .....}
```

Any ideas how to parse it?

Comment: It's not clear how the numbers and the room name in the input file map to the output. Is the first number the key? The rest of the numbers the list in the output dictionary?

Comment: the first number is the current room, and the rest of the numbers the neighbours

Comment: Do you want to store the room name as well? It might be better to have a dictionary where the key is the room name, and the value is a list. The first element of the list is the room number, and the second is a list of neighbors: `d['Room1'] = [1, [2,]]; d['Room2'] = [2, [1, 5]]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: better go the other direction, this is the better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output contains strings, so you can skip the `int` calls.

If the first element is to be the key, the rest the values (ignoring the room name), a dict comprehension is enough:

```
with open( "data.txt", "r" ) as input_data:
    data = {elems[0]: elems[1:-1] 
            for line in input_data for elems in (line.split(','),)}
```

The `for elems in (line.split(','),)` section assigns just one value (the output of `line.split(',')` to `elems`; it works around limitations in comprehension syntax.

Since this is comma-separated data, I'd use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) here:

```
import csv

with open( "data.txt", "rb" ) as input_data:
    reader = csv.reader(input_data)
    data = {row[0]: row[1:-1] for row in reader}
```

As you can see, this simplifies handling each line significantly.

Add `int()` calls if desired:

```
data = {int(row[0]): map(int, row[1:-1]) for row in reader}
```

Answer (score 0):

are u looking for something like this?

```
with open( "data.txt", "r" ) as input_data:
    input_list= input_data.readlines()

new_dict = {}
for mem in input_list:
    a = mem.split(',')
    new_dict[a[0]] = a[1:len(a) - 1]

print new_dict
//{'1': ['2'], '2': ['1', '5'], '5': ['2', '332']}
```

may be it can more optimized